# Why there is needing for inflation?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

Within the big bang theory, how can I conceptually understand the needing for an inflationary expansion? Why the CMB should be different than the observed one without inflation? Really the concept please.

PS in case the requirement is due to the cosmological principle. In this case I understand that if I have to see the same CMB every where ( say outside our observable universe or even inside but being at midway ) then inflation is necessary.  To clarify what I mean here: with the same thinking, strictly applying the cosmological principle tell me that the universe is spatially infinite ( especially if curvature is , as it seems, quite unity) .

Comment: This question is quite broad. What about [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)#Motivations) is not clear to you?

Comment: @javier I think the answer is as I suggested in the question. ...basically without inflation there should be no universe outside the observable one... something like that.  I do not understand why it is said two far away point can't be at same T...

Comment: [Flatness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatness_problem) &
[Horizon problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_problem)

Comment: Thanks I will try again to get the point about the two problems

Comment: @Arthur. Ok . I am always stuck to the same problem. It is assumed that two opposite patches of the CMB had to be in contact at big bang? In other words:it is assumed that  all universe (observable and beyond) originated from the same minuscule speck? Because if it so, without inflation there should be nothing out there. ...

Comment: Watch lecture of Dr. Lawrence Krauss on A universe from Nothing. Just look it up on YouTube or read his book. He covers maths, physics, and observations and how all of that point towards the need for inflation theory.

Comment: @LostCause. I will.  Though I am sure I will understand for getting again in trouble after some time. :) It is really matter or visualisation. The same for my recent question about size at big bang. Is the same question after all.